# Where to meet another traveller at Heathrow T5

Tags: airports, london, lhr, group-travel

I am going to arrive at London Heathrow Terminal 1, a friend of mine is going to land on a different flight at T3 slightly earlier, and then we are flying out together on a connecting flight from T5.

> Could you suggest me a good place for us to meet at the airport?

My guess would be somewhere at the entrance of T5, but I am not familiar with the airport.

1. Is there a good place to meet at T5, such as the entrance or a designated meeting point?
2. Is there an additional security control for travellers on connecting flights leaving at T5? Is it before or after the meeting point?

Comment: I am not sure if [this helps](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/airport-maps).

Comment: Will either of you need to re-check bags, or can you both stay airside? (Will make a difference on the best place)

Comment: @Gagravarr No bag re-check I think - both flights are with British Airways, and we don't go to/come from the US.

Comment: Why not meet at your departing gate, since it's the place you'll both be required to go anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heathrow does have some meeting points, but most of these are aimed at meeting arriving passengers landside. I'd suggest you avoid those, as otherwise you'll have to clear immigration which you don't really want to do if you can help it.

For both of you, when you land, follow the (largely) purple Flight Connections signs. You can see an example of what to look for [in this answer on a T5-T5 connection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/23792/26) - it's largely the same signs in all the terminals. Flight Connections will eventually lead you to somewhere where you can take a bus to Terminal 5, make sure you get the right one as it's a different bus for each terminal! Pretty well sign-posted though.

On arrival at Terminal 5, the bus will drop you off at the ground level, and you'll take the lifts or escalators up. Follow Flight Connections here, and you should see this:
[image: Photo of T5A flight connections, from www.flickr.com/photos/22819720@N02/]

If you still need your onward boarding card, head to the connections desk on your right. Armed with your boarding card, straight on to the connections boarding card check, then upstairs for transfer security. Chances are, you're looking at about 45-60 minutes from stepping off your plane in T1/T2/T3 until you've cleared T5 security, with walking, wait for buses, and security queues. Times will vary for both of you, so it's hard to say who'll be first!

At this point, you have two options. One is head straight to your gate in T5, and wait there for your friend. There's seating at every gate, and the first one there can have a seat while you await the other. There's free wifi in the terminal, IIRC after watching an advert, so you can get online while you're there.

Otherwise, there's a few restaurants and bars in terminal 5, [listed here](http://www.heathrowairport.com/shop,-eat,-relax-and-enjoy/restaurants-a_z?terminal=Heathrow%20T5) and [shown on this printable map](http://www.heathrowairport.com/static/Heathrow/Downloads/PDF/Heathrow_T5_Map.pdf). You can always pick one, and whoever gets there first gets the first round of drinks in, the other finds them in there on their arrival!